# Detecting bold, underline text and headings in word document with openxml sdk in c#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I would like to detect different styles and heading in selected word document with the openxml sdk in C#. This is what I have:

```
 public string getWordDescription(string path)
        {
            string text = "";
            System.IO.Packaging.Package wordPackage = Package.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
WordprocessingDocument.Open(wordPackage))
            {              
                Body body = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                if (body != null)
                {
                    foreach (Paragraph par in body.Descendants<Paragraph>())
                    {                                              
                        text += par.InnerText;
                        text += "<br />";                                              
                    }
                }
            }
            return text;
        }
```

So while looping the paragraphs I would like to somehow detect if there is some styling applied or if the paragraph is heading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that Paragraphs are blocks and blocks are made up of runs.  So in your foreach loops you'll need an inner loop to loop through the runs.  Run elements container RunProperty elements that describe the inline formatting.  Or I believe you can only use one loops like the following

```
foreach (Run run in body.Descendants<Run>())
{
   RunProperties props = run.Descendants<RunProperties>();
   if(props.Descendants<Bold>().First() != null) 
   {
      //then do something
   }

   text += run.Text;
   text += "<br />";                                              
}
```

Comment: what you've said is absolutely correct, but properties are applied to paragraphs as well and you'll have to iterate through them as well to check if styling is applied.

Comment: thanks, I forgot about the styles.  I was refering only to inline styles.  good catch

Comment: i think this might break as you are assigning an enumerable to a single instance of RunProperties

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
private RunStyles checkForEmphasis(Paragraph pTag)
    {

        bool isItalic = false;
        bool isBold = false;
        bool isUnderline = false;
        foreach (Run r in pTag.Descendants<Run>())
        {
            if (r.RunProperties != null)
            {
                RunProperties rProp = r.RunProperties;
                if (rProp.Italic != null)
                {
                    int x;

                    isItalic = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isItalic = false;
                }
                if (rProp.Bold != null)
                {
                    isBold = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isBold = false;
                }
                if (rProp.Underline != null)
                {
                    isUnderline = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isUnderline = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isItalic = false;
                isBold = false;
                isUnderline = false;
            }
        }
        if (isItalic && isBold && isUnderline)
        {
            return RunStyles.AllStyles;
        }
        else if (isBold && isItalic)
        {
            return RunStyles.BoldItalic;
        }
        else if (isBold && isUnderline)
        {
            return RunStyles.BoldUnderLine;
        }
        else if (isItalic && isUnderline)
        {
            return RunStyles.ItalicUnderLine;
        }
        else if (isItalic)
        {
            return RunStyles.Italic;
        }
        else if (isBold)
        {
            return RunStyles.Bold;
        }
        else if (isUnderline)
        {
            return RunStyles.UnderLine;
        }
        else
        {
            return RunStyles.NoStyle;
        }

    }
```

The Enum RunStyles

```
enum RunStyles
{
    AllStyles = 1,
    BoldItalic = 2,
    BoldUnderLine = 3,
    ItalicUnderLine = 4,
    Italic = 5,
    Bold = 6,
    UnderLine = 7,
    NoStyle = 0
}
```

Based on this you can do your stuff. This is for complete paragraph.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
//using MS word introp object   

 public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetBoldItalicUnderline(string strfilename, int style)//style=1 is bold and style=2 is italic and style=3
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application Objword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            //creating the object of document class  
            Document objdoc = new Document();
           // Document objdoc = Objword.Documents.Add();
            try
            {
                dynamic FilePath = strfilename;
                dynamic NA = System.Type.Missing;
                objdoc = Objword.Documents.Open
                              (ref FilePath, ref NA, ref NA, ref NA, ref NA,
                               ref NA, ref NA, ref NA, ref NA,
                               ref NA, ref NA, ref NA, ref NA,
                               ref NA, ref NA, ref NA
                               );
                if (style == 1)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = objdoc.Content;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find find = rng.Find;
                    find.Font.Bold = 1;
                    find.Format = true;
                    while (find.Execute())
                    {
                        data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rng.Text, "Bold"));
                    }
                }
                if (style == 2)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngitalic = objdoc.Content;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find finditalic = rngitalic.Find;
                    finditalic.Font.Italic = 1;
                    finditalic.Format = true;
                    while (finditalic.Execute())
                    {
                        data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngitalic.Text, "Italic"));
                    }
                }
                if (style == 3)
                {
                    //Simgle Underline
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderline = objdoc.Content;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderline = rngunderline.Find;
                    findunderline.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;
                    findunderline.Format = true;
                    while (findunderline.Execute())
                    {
                        // data.Add(rngunderline.Text);
                        data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderline.Text, "wdUnderlineSingle"));
                    }
                    //Dash
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineDash = objdoc.Content;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineDash = rngunderlineDash.Find;
                    findunderlineDash.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineDash;
                    findunderlineDash.Format = true;
                    while (findunderlineDash.Execute())
                    {
                        //data.Add(rngunderlineDash.Text);
                        data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineDash.Text, "wdUnderlineDash"));
                    }
                    //DashHeavy



Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineDashHeavy = objdoc.Content;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineDashHeavy = rngunderlineDashHeavy.Find;
                findunderlineDashHeavy.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineDashHeavy;
                findunderlineDashHeavy.Format = true;
                while (findunderlineDashHeavy.Execute())
                {
                    //  data.Add(rngunderlineDashHeavy.Text);
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineDashHeavy.Text, "wdUnderlineDashHeavy"));
                }
                //DashLong
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineDashLong = objdoc.Content;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineDashLong = rngunderlineDashLong.Find;
                findunderlineDashLong.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineDashLong;
                findunderlineDashLong.Format = true;
                while (findunderlineDashLong.Execute())
                {
                    // data.Add(rngunderlineDashLong.Text);
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineDashLong.Text, "wdUnderlineDashLong"));
                }
                //DashLongHeavy
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineDashLonghv = objdoc.Content;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineDashLonghv = rngunderlineDashLonghv.Find;
                findunderlineDashLonghv.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineDashLongHeavy;
                findunderlineDashLonghv.Format = true;
                while (findunderlineDashLonghv.Execute())
                {
                    // data.Add(rngunderlineDashLonghv.Text);
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineDashLonghv.Text, "wdUnderlineDashLongHeavy"));
                }
                //DotDash
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineDotDash = objdoc.Content;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineDotDash = rngunderlineDotDash.Find;
                findunderlineDotDash.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineDotDash;
                findunderlineDotDash.Format = true;
                while (findunderlineDotDash.Execute())
                {
                    //data.Add(rngunderlineDotDash.Text);
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineDotDash.Text, "wdUnderlineDotDash"));
                }
                //DotDashHeavy
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineDotDashHv = objdoc.Content;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineDotDashHv = rngunderlineDotDashHv.Find;
                findunderlineDotDashHv.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineDotDashHeavy;
                findunderlineDotDashHv.Format = true;
                while (findunderlineDotDashHv.Execute())
                {
                    //data.Add(rngunderlineDotDashHv.Text);
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineDotDashHv.Text, "wdUnderlineDotDashHeavy"));
                }
                //DotDotDash

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineDotDotDash = objdoc.Content;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineDotDotDash = rngunderlineDotDotDash.Find;
                findunderlineDotDotDash.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineDotDotDash;
                findunderlineDotDotDash.Format = true;
                while (findunderlineDotDotDash.Execute())
                {
                    // data.Add(rngunderlineDotDotDash.Text);
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineDotDotDash.Text, "wdUnderlineDotDotDash"));
                }

                //DotDotDashHeavy
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineDotDotDashHv = objdoc.Content;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineDotDotDashHv = rngunderlineDotDotDashHv.Find;
                findunderlineDotDotDashHv.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineDotDotDashHeavy;
                findunderlineDotDotDashHv.Format = true;
                while (findunderlineDotDotDashHv.Execute())
                {
                    //data.Add(rngunderlineDotDotDashHv.Text);
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineDotDotDashHv.Text, "wdUnderlineDotDotDashHeavy"));
                }
                //Dotted
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineDotted = objdoc.Content;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineDotted = rngunderlineDotted.Find;
                findunderlineDotted.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineDotted;
                findunderlineDotted.Format = true;
                while (findunderlineDotted.Execute())
                {
                    // data.Add(rngunderlineDotted.Text);
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineDotted.Text, "wdUnderlineDotted"));
                }
                //DottedHeavy
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineDottedHv = objdoc.Content;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineDottedHv = rngunderlineDottedHv.Find;
                findunderlineDottedHv.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineDottedHeavy;
                findunderlineDottedHv.Format = true;
                while (findunderlineDottedHv.Execute())
                {
                    //data.Add(rngunderlineDottedHv.Text);
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineDottedHv.Text, "wdUnderlineDottedHeavy"));
                }
                //DoubleUnderline
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineDouble = objdoc.Content;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineDouble = rngunderlineDouble.Find;
                findunderlineDouble.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineDouble;
                findunderlineDouble.Format = true;
                while (findunderlineDouble.Execute())
                {
                    // data.Add(rngunderlineDouble.Text);
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineDouble.Text, "wdUnderlineDouble"));
                }
                //Thick
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineThick = objdoc.Content;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineThick = rngunderlineThick.Find;
                findunderlineThick.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineThick;
                findunderlineThick.Format = true;
                while (findunderlineThick.Execute())
                {
                    // data.Add(rngunderlineThick.Text);
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineThick.Text, "wdUnderlineThick"));
                }
                //Wavy
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineWavy = objdoc.Content;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineWavy = rngunderlineWavy.Find;
                findunderlineWavy.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineWavy;
                findunderlineWavy.Format = true;
                while (findunderlineWavy.Execute())
                {
                    // data.Add(rngunderlineWavy.Text);
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineWavy.Text, "wdUnderlineWavy"));
                }
                //wavyDouble
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineWavyDbl = objdoc.Content;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineWavyDbl = rngunderlineWavyDbl.Find;
                findunderlineWavyDbl.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineWavyDouble;
                findunderlineWavyDbl.Format = true;
                while (findunderlineWavyDbl.Execute())
                {
                    //data.Add(rngunderlineWavyDbl.Text);
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineWavyDbl.Text, "wdUnderlineWavyDouble"));
                }
                //WavyHeavy
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngunderlineWavyHv = objdoc.Content;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findunderlineWavyHv = rngunderlineWavyHv.Find;
                findunderlineWavyHv.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineWavyHeavy;
                findunderlineWavyHv.Format = true;
                while (findunderlineWavyHv.Execute())
                {
                    //  data.Add(rngunderlineWavyHv.Text);
                    data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rngunderlineWavyHv.Text, "wdUnderlineWavyHeavy"));
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (objdoc != null)
            {
                ((_Document)objdoc).Close();
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objdoc);
                objdoc = null;
            }
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("winword");
            foreach (var process in processes)
            {
                process.Close();
            }
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this work?  When I use this it does not detect bold or italic since those values appear to be -1 (not 1) when you query rng.Font.Bold or rng.Font.Italic.  Even programmatically setting rng.Font.Bold = 1 and then immediately checking returns a value of -1.